# Using different arrays in one swtich case C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, switch-statement, maze

I'm doing "Unblock Me"-like game in C#.
Using buttons, and arrays as a map.
lvl1 array is a board/map of level 1. And when the blocks(buttons) dynamically creates and adds to panel, i want to color them. When i completes the level it must clear the panel and re draws the board but this time it must read board/map from lvl2 array. So the question is how to set name of the array in swtich case loop dynamically?
Here's the code:

```
int[,] lvl1 = 
            {
            {1,1,2,3,3,4,0},
            {0,0,2,0,5,4,0},
            {6,0,99,99,5,4,89},
            {6,0,7,7,8,8,0},
            {9,10,0,11,12,12,0},
            {9,10,0,11,13,13,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
               };
      switch (lvl1[i, j])
                    {
                        case 1:

                            lvl1[i,j] = 1;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            break;

                        case 2:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 2;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
                            break;

                        case 3:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 3;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
                            break;

                        case 4:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 4;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
                            break;

                        case 5:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 5;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.Violet;
                            break;
                        case 6:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 6;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                            break;
                        case 7:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 7;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                            break;
                        case 8:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 8;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.Teal;
                            break;
                        case 9:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 9;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
                            break;
                        case 10:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 10;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
                            break;
                        case 11:

                            lvl1[i, j] = 11;
                            btn.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You use an different variable to point to that.

```
int[,] currentLevel;

currentLevel = lvl1;
```

Then in the checks

```
switch (currentLevel[i, j])
...
```

And when you want another level, you just `currentLevel = lvl2`

Comment: yeah. i tried that. It showed some error like no override with 2 arguments?? something like that

Comment: can you tell me whats the type of the currentlevel? is it string? or...??

Comment: @НямбаярА. As shown in the answer, it's `int[,]`, the same as the levels as it should be.

Comment: oh i see. I tried this methos but i have an compiling error, still. It says 
 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form2.lvl1' 
I googlded it. I tried  new int[]; but still. Dont work?

Comment: @НямбаярА. You have to set the value inside a function, not in declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of arrays of levels, so instead of having `int[,] lvl1`, you will have `List<int[,]>` levels, then you can use any game level from that list.